# Characteristic of a lattice that subsets contain their meets and joins

Tags: lattice-orders

A lattice is defined if a poset $T$ has a infimum and supremum for any finite $S \subseteq T$.

What is a lattice called, where $\forall S \in \mathcal{P}(T). inf(S) \in S \wedge sup(S) \in S$?

I have a feeling that such a lattice would always be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: In the definition, first paragraph, don't you mean for any *finite* $S \subseteq T$? Otherwise the question doesn't make any sense (and the definition would be wrong).

Comment: @amrsa Yes thank you

Comment: And I also suppose for all non-empty subset $S$ of $T$, right? Because the supremum and the infimum of the empty set don't belong to the empty set (and sometimes they do exist).

Answer (score 2):

A lattice $L$ for which every subset $A$ we have $\bigvee A \in A$ and $\bigwedge A \in A$ is necessarily a finite chain, that is, its ordered elements look like
$$a_1 \prec a_2 \prec \cdots \prec a_n,$$
where $a \prec b$ means $a < b$ and there exist no $c$ with $a < c < b$.
In this case, $\bigwedge A = \min A$ and $\bigvee A = \max A$.

Indeed, if there exist $a,b \in L$ with $a \nleq b$ and $b \nleq a$, then set $A = \{a,b\}$ and you have that $\bigwedge A \notin A$ and $\bigvee A \notin A$.
If there is an infinite chain $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $a_n < a_{n+1}$, then set $A = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$, and $\bigvee A \notin A$.
If there is an infinite chain $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ and $a_n > a_{n+1}$, then set $A = \{a_n: n \in \mathbb N\}$, and $\bigwedge A \notin A$.

So you see that actually $\mathbb Z$ is not one such lattice...

Comment: Okay, basically we define such a lattice as a finite chain of coverings? But I don't understand why it doesn't work for infinite chains? It seems to like you take a meet/join of an infinite subset, which shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @hgiesel for example, the interval [0,1] of the real line is an infinite chain. The subset (0,1) does not satisfy the property you mention (i.e. is not a complete sublattice), since its join is 1 and its meet is 0.

Comment: @hgiesel William DeMeo gave a good example. And generally, if a chain is infinite, we can always pick a subset as one of the two examples I gave, that is, it either doesn't satisfy the [Ascending Chain Condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascending_chain_condition) or its dual, the Descending Chain Condition. Check that Wikipedia article and the section 'Comments'.